# Python selenium function to open a new URL doesn't work with Chrome user profile

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get python to open chrome with my personal chrome profile and then run a website.
So, I wrote the below code. My problem is that if I just write the last 2 lines of code, chrome opens and runs the URL but as soon as I introduce the first 3 lines (the non-import lines), it opens up a new chrome session with my user but doesn't run the URL.
What am I missing here? Why is it one or the other?

```
from selenium import webdriver
# from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
# from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\myPC\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data") #Path to your chrome profile
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\myPC\\Desktop\\BrowserAutomation\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')
driver.get("https://www.python.org")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close all the chrome browser instances in your machine and then run the existing code along with `driver.quit()` directive as below

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument(
    "user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\myPC\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")  # Path to your chrome profile

w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='.\chromedriver.exe', chrome_options=options)

w.get('https://www.python.org')

w.quit()
```

Comment: This did everything but the w.quit closed the browser after calling the URL. I removed that line but everything else looks good. Thanks.

Comment: please add your feature next to `w.get()` before `w.quit()`